# Netbeans: Error in loading component property: Other components->

Tags: java, netbeans, reinstall

And it continues:

mainPanel->panMain->border Cannot read property.

This is the result attempting to go from Netbeans 6.8 to Netbeans 7.0 and 7.1 and 7.2. the latter two don't support the Swing Application Framework and 7.0 won't let me build new projects so I am on a crusade to get back to 6.8 in order to support and maintain a large system in use by some very large companies indeed. I've asked some questions on the netbeans forums and gotten minimal response, only a small fraction of which was helpful.

stackOverflow, however, knows everything, which is why I'm here.

Can anybody help me figure out this error condition? I have been pounding on this for a week.

If my software didn't maintain some sort of backwards compatibility path, we'd have been out of business long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that this error is caused by building a project with a newer version of Netbeans and then trying to work on it with an older version. Lesson learned? Don't create a project with NB 6.8, build it with NB 7.0.x and then try to revert to NB 6.8 or 6.9 because of bugs in 7.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I fixed it by activating "Java SE".  For some reason when I installed Netbeans, Java SE wasn't activated.  The way to activate is by going to Tools->Plugins->Installed and then check the Java SE box and then click on Activate.  Restart Netbeans IDE.  That's all folks and it worked for me.